# Using function from another js file

Tags: javascript

Hi Im writing a bot that uses js and im trying to use couple of files but I cant use function from other js files, is there a way that I can use several files?
Thanks for your help
Just some example:

fl.js:

```
bla = function(x){
  return 100*x;
}
```

index.js:

```
var num=prompt('Enter number');
console.alert(dd.bla(num));
```

Comment: First things first are you loading the files in the proper order?

Comment: The bot uses JS, or the bot is JS?  How is the bot run?  How are you including js files into the file you want to use the functions in?

Comment: Hi @Llama5543, welcome to stackoverflow! Please consider posting some relevant code to help us better understand your problem!

Comment: Bot is JS, runs through CMD sorry Im a bit new to JS Im including files just how included files C#

Comment: Javascript is normally used for running code inside a browser, not from CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Use following pattern:

In module.js file:

```
(function ($, module) {

    module.add = function (a, b) {
        return a+b;
    };

    module.subtract = function (a, b) {
        return a-b;
    };
}(jQuery, window.module = window.module || {}));
```

And usage of module as following:

```
(function ($, module) {

    $(function () {

        $("#add").on("click", function(){
            var first = $("#first").val();
            var second = $("#second").val();

            var result = module.add(first, second);

            alert(result);
        });
    });

}(jQuery, module));
```

[plnkr test](https://plnkr.co/edit/XolLqzMJleaMyIwSnTvi)